# What happens with modules and themes when I rebuild the cache?

Tags: 8, caching

Just for learning, this [document](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_flush_all_caches/8.3.x) explains me in a "ballpark" way how cache rebuild works, but I want to know more about *"Updates the system with latest information about extensions (modules and themes)."*

What happens with modules and themes when I rebuild the cache?

Answer (score 0):

To create a page Drupal needs to make several database queries. This can slow down websites with a lot of traffic. To make websites faster Drupal stores web pages in a cache.

Before Drupal 8, the common mantra was **drush cc all (i.e. drush clear-cache)**. Now, in Drupal 8, it's **drush cache-rebuild** OR **drush cr**.

Caching is widespread in Drupal and creates many interdependencies. Improperly or incomplete cache flushing operations can cause the site to fatal error. In order to *guarantee that old data is properly flushed and the site stays up and running*,  **drush cache-rebuild both rebuilds or re-bootstraps the Drupal site in    addition to clearing the cache**

In-short, Drush's **cache-rebuild** command does the following:

- Clears the APC cache
- Bootstraps Drupal
- Calls drupal_rebuild()
- Clears the Drush cache (to maintain consistency with Drupal 7's drush cache-clear command)

If you would like to dig more into this check out https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/659f67712adab143a2c921f9f23828782e414e8d/commands/core/cache.drush.inc#L263 at the end of the file, look at function drush_cache_rebuild().

Thanks!